# python задача для начинающих

Tags: python

Прошу помочь решить задачу. Используя декомпозицию функций.
Вам выгрузили список с анкетами потенциальных клиентов, которые заинтересовались покупкой подписки на здоровую еду. Вам нужно обработать эти значения и сказать, какие анкеты подходят (а какие нет) для дальнейшего обзвона колл-центром.

Условия, которым должна удовлетворять анкета:

Есть контактная информация: номер телефона.
Контактный номер начинается либо с восьмёрки, либо с семёрки и состоит из десяти символов.
Город проживания: Москва.
Мое решение до конца не верное. Его нужно скорректировать.

```
applications = [
         'name=Аня,phone=8800234 ,city=москва',
         'name=КОЛЯ,phone=8800900871 ,city=МОСКВА',
         'name=Валентина,phone=7950900871 ,city=волгоград',
         'name=,phone=7999901871,city=москва',
         'name=Иван,phone=7999901871,city=москва',
         'name=Инга,phone=,city=москва'] 

def check_phone(phone):
    b = phone.replace(' ', '') 
    a = b.split(',')
    if len(a[1]) is not None and len(a[1]) == 16: 
        print("True")
        if a[1][6] == "7" or a[1][6] == "8":
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")
    else: 
        print("False")

def check_city(city = "москва"):
    normalized_string = city.lower()
    index = normalized_string.find(city)
    if index != -1:
        print ("False")
    else:
        print ("True")
     
def check_application(applications):
    for application in applications:
        b = application.replace(' ', '')
        phone_one = check_phone(application)
        city_one = check_city(application)

        if phone_one == "True" and city_one == "True":
            print(b, "True")
        else:
            print(b, "False")

check_application(applications)
```

Здесь нужно добавить еще функцию  def find_valid_applications(applications):

Результат должен быть:

```
find_valid_applications(applications)
name=Аня,phone=8800234 ,city=москва --- False
```

...
итд

Comment: Начни здесь: [ask]